# Is there a way to set up personal dashboards

Tags: tfs, dashboard

Is there a way to set up a personal dashboard for TFS that is in addition to the team dashboard?

We have a group of users who want to see different information than what is on the team dashboard, and would like their own dashboard/view to show things like Tasks Assigned to them, Open Backlog Items, etc. But this would only be for the individual (others want to see different queries and other widgets depending on their tasks in a team).

Comment: such a must feature :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no personal dashboards at present. However, there are work item query tokens like `@Me` so you can have one query that is personalized for whoever is viewing the dashboard.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, hopefully this can be a future enhancement. Personally as I have 4 different projects in TFS I would like to log in and see all my tasks and such from all 4 of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can view all work items assigned to you in web based TFS
http://{TFS Server}/{ProjectsCollectionName}/_work

[You will see your dashboard as attched screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgEBp.png)